# Why can't red interface with node.js while rebol can?

Tags: node.js, rebol, red

I just stumbled upon this:

https://trello.com/c/yGGIM3Hl/32-nodejs-interface-for-rebol-to-pave-the-way-for-red

> While Red doesn't build on a standard toolchain and is not something you can add in wrapped up as a native node.js NPM package, Rebol can do just that today (if someone were willing to do a little work!) Then something like:
>
> ```
>  npm install rebol-eval
> ```
>
> Followed by something dumb; give it a string, get back a string:
>
> ```
>   var rebolEval = require("rebol-eval");
>
>  rebolEval.newContext(function (err, rebol) {
>      if (err) {
>          console.error("context alloc failure: " + err);
>          return;
>       }
>      rebol.eval("1 + 1", function (err, res)) {
>          if (err) {
>              console.err("Evaluation failed " + err);
>          } else {
>              console.log(res);
>          }
>      }
>  }
> ```

Is it about being able to call rebol from nodeJs ? Why would rebol be able to and not red as I thought red was supposed to be compatible with rebol.

Comment: It appears that someone has done the work to write a node.js interface so you can call rebol code from within node.js, but apparently (according to you) one has not done that for red.  Even though red is another implementation of the rebol language, it would still need its own implementation of a node.js interface in order to be used from node.js because it is a separate binary from rebol.

Comment: What you found here is a proposal, it hasn't been done.  In theory, given libRed as a C API there's not really much difference between the two languages interacting with the C++ toolchain.  In practice there are some nebulous issues affecting the external interface.  See [handle lifetime](https://forum.rebol.info/t/lifetime-of-handles-given-back-to-c-code/343) and [handle mutability](https://forum.rebol.info/t/should-values-given-to-c-through-api-handles-be-mutable/345).  If this is an area you know about, I encourage you to weigh in.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would rebol be able to and not red as I thought red was supposed to be compatible with rebol.

The fact that nobody did such integration does not mean that it cannot be done. Moreover the "compatibility" you are mentioning is at the language level, not toolchain level.

Actually, it should be fairly simple to achieve integration with Node.js, thanks to the [libRed API](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/libred.html), which allow Red's runtime and interpreter to be embedded in pretty much [any software](http://www.red-lang.org/2017/03/062-libred-and-macros.html).

Comment: No such code exists, but [see my note above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911471/why-cant-red-interface-with-node-js-while-rebol-can#comment80842482_46911471) and links therein.